# Rails 4: SQLException: no such table:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

i am running the following in Rails4:

> $ bundle exec rake db:migrate
>
> == 201405270646 AddAttachmentImageToPins: migrating ===========================
>   -- change_table(:pins) rake aborted! StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
>
> SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: pins: ALTER TABLE "pins" ADD
>   "image_file_n ame"
>   varchar(255)c:/Sites/pinteresting/db/migrate/201405270646_add_attachment_im
>   age_to_pins.rb:4:in `block in up'
>   c:/Sites/pinteresting/db/migrate/201405270646_add_attachment_image_to_pins.rb:3:
>   in`up' c:in `migrate' Tasks: TOP => db:migrate (See full trace by
>   running task with --trace)

I can't undestand why i am getting this error.

Here is my github: https://github.com/frankzk/pinteresting

Thanks for the help

Migration file:

```
class AddAttachmentImageToPins < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :pins do |t|
        t.attachment :image
    end
  end


  def self.down
    drop_attached_file :pins, :image
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post your migration file?

Comment: Have you deleted an older migration file?

Comment: @user2675613 I have already posted

Comment: I suggest that you make `rake db:drop` then `rake db:create` and then `rake db:migrate`. This will drop your database and recreate it and run all migrations correctly (I hope). Tell us if it works.

Comment: @TamerShlash it doesnt works. It shows me the same error after runing rake db:migrate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has to do with the filename of the migration.

When running migrations, Rails looks at the timestamps in the filenames to figure out the order to run them in.

If you look at your migration files:

```
db/migrate/
├── 20140526033741_devise_create_users.rb
├── 20140526222538_create_pins.rb
├── 20140527032853_add_user_id_to_pins.rb
└── 201405270646_add_attachment_image_to_pins.rb
```

You'll see that add_attachment_image_to_pins.rb is 2 characters shorter than the others for some reason. So it's trying to run this one first and at that point, the pins table hasn't been created leading to the `no such table: pins` error

Renaming it to `20140527064600_add_attachment_image_to_pins.rb` allowed me to run the migrations successfully.

Comment: bump!
I do not have any migration files with shorter names. How do I fix this?
tried 

Tried this http://stackoverflow.com/a/26534125/2615428