# rake db:migrate error tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am trying to run `rake db:migrate` and am receiving an error in the console.

It seems as though I am creating a table that already exists, yet I don't know how to remove the old table, or reset the db to start fresh.

I don't have any users so erasing or starting from fresh won't be an issue.

> create_table(:users) rake aborted! StandardError: An error has
>   occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
>
> SQLite3::SQLException: table "users" already exists: CREATE TABLE
>   "users" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "email"
>   varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, "encrypted_password" varchar(255)
>   DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, "reset_password_token" varchar(255),
>   "reset_password_sent_at" datetime, "remember_created_at" datetime,
>   "sign_in_count" integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, "current_sign_in_at"
>   datetime, "last_sign_in_at" datetime, "current_sign_in_ip"
>   varchar(255), "last_sign_in_ip" varchar(255), "created_at" datetime,
>   "updated_at" datetime)
>   /Users/jovanhernandez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in
>   `initialize'

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind erasing data you can run

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

and that should fix it. Otherwise you can for the moment comment out the part of the content causing problems in the change (or up) method in your migration and then run the migrations. After the migration is run uncomment the migration.

Doing this tricks rails into accepting that the migrations are up to date.

Comment: I tried this sequence, and still get this in the console when I rake db:migrate...

`rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "email" varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL/Users/jovanhernandez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'`

Comment: Now you have 2 different error messages, which one is the latest? One in this comment and one in your edited question

Comment: Sorry, this situation is fluid so I did your steps above, deleted my old migration, then created new user. This is error now:

`-- change_table(:users)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "email" varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL/Users/jovanhernandez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'`

Current sidebar reads this: http://imgur.com/9FXbPq1

Comment: how does that migration look?

Comment: I'm having trouble formating code in stacksocial, so here is a link screen shot. I will also try and copy paste the code below: http://imgur.com/CXX3k8q

EDIT: Code is too long to copy paste. sorry, hope that screen shot is sufficient.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you!! that seems to have worked! I now see this:

`== 20141023181234 AddDeviseToUsers: migrating =================================
-- create_table(:users)
   -> 0.0075s
-- add_index(:users, :email, {:unique=>true})
   -> 0.0017s
-- add_index(:users, :reset_password_token, {:unique=>true})
   -> 0.0014s
== 20141023181234 AddDeviseToUsers: migrated (0.0109s) ========================`

Comment: Hello, I am now getting an error with `heroku run rake db:migrate`. please see screen shot... http://i.imgur.com/GvyKwKg.png
I tried heroku run rake db:drop and heroku run rake db:create but those commands aren't recognized.

Answer (score 2):

You can reset database by using

```
$ rake db:reset
```

Or if you want to undo your migration you can use

```
$ rake db:rollback
```

Or if you want to update your table, you may change it in your migration file from create_table to change_table

```
create_table :users do |t|
```

to

```
change_table(:users) do |t|
```

Answer (score 2):

Look like you have not any users migration but you have migration to change the users table.Means you are trying to alter users table without existence of it.If you have schema file then you can load your database from there by using  rake db:schema:dump command.

Answer (score 1):

You already have the users table created. Looks like the migration was already run and there is no need to run it again.

Comment: Does SQLite have anything to do with this error? Here is what I am getting.

I tried this sequence, and still get this in the console when I rake db:migrate...

`rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "email" varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL/Users/jovanhernandez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'`